# UIImagePickerController doesn't display rotate button

Tags: ipad, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

It's an iPhone app running in iPad in iOS7. In iPhone it works fine.
However in iPad, the rotate button is not displayed and the view is like cut off on the top.
I'm not doing anything strange with the image picker. Here's how I show it:

```
- (void)showImagePickerWithSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
     UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
     imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeImage];
     imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType;
     imagePicker.delegate = self;
     imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

     //Select front facing camera if available
     if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera && [UIImagePickerController   isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront])
     {
         imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
     }

     [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you post the screen shot of iPad app?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I edited the question to add the screenshot.

Comment: @mdonati did you got solution?